# QA plugin for intellij

Tags: plugins, intellij-idea, checkstyle

I am trying to load my customized checkstyle configuration xml in the QA Plug in for IntelliJ. 
The following is the graphic interface that I get in order to configure it:

[image]

In the label "**Jar file**", what am I supposed to upload? What kind of jar are they talking about? I have only the checkstyle xml configuration file.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to use Checkstyle I would recommend to use [CheckStyle-IDEA](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/1065) instead. Its included version of Checkstyle is much more up to date then the one provided by QAPlug.

Regarding your question, I think the dialog you presented is to add additional Checkstlye checks, e.g. [sevntu-checkstyle](https://github.com/sevntu-checkstyle/sevntu.checkstyle). If you would like to have such additional checks then you would need to add a configuration and a jar file with the checks.

To import your checkstyle.xml try as described in [import and export analysis profiles](http://qaplug.com/about/tutorials/#tutorial3) on the QAPlug homepage. There it says "You are able to import several coding rules configuration files (eg. Checkstyle, PMD, FindBugs) to one profile simply be repeating import action."

Answer (score 0):

1. First, save your desired configuration xml file somewhere locally on your computer.
2. Right-Click/Ctrl-click on the file or directory you want analyzed with QAplug and click "Analyze Code". This should bring up an interface saying "Specify Analysis Scope"
3. Under the "Analysis Profile" heading, tick the Run with Chose Profile button. Then click on the `...` box to search for the proper directory.
4. This brings up another window titled `Coding Rules`. Click the `+` button that pops up and select either `project profile` or `ide profile` according to taste.
5. This brings up yet another window titled `New Profile`. Name your profile appropriately. Tick the `import profile` button and then it will allow you to `import profile from` and point it at the .xml file you saved in #1. Hit Ok.
6. Now under the analysis profile, you should be able to choose the newly created profile. Click OK and you're good to go.